# Multiple WHERE IN on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, optimization

I am not very experienced with sql queries and looking for an efficient way to perform the same WHERE IN condition on multiple columns.

More specifically, i'm doing the following:

```
SELECT a, b 
FROM links 
WHERE a IN (90696, 110083, ... 147455) 
  OR b IN (90696, 110083, ... 147455)
```

Since both IN-lists are identical and can contain several hundreds of items, the above query just doesn't feel very right to me.

If it helps (but I don't think so, actually):

- the following condition is always met: `row[x].a < row[x].b` for all rows x in Table links.
- Im using MySQL InnoDB. Yet, I'm open to different database solutions if would significantly improve performance.
- Currently, the items of the WHERE-IN clause are computed. However, I could also acquire them by an additional query (which would actually be the union of two queries).

**Edit:**

The IN-list could be constructed by

```
SELECT i_id as l FROM t_i WHERE id=x
UNION ALL
SELECT o_id as l FROM t_o WHERE id=x
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to check each combination of a/b and i_id/o_id

then simple rewrite to join is like this:

```
SELECT a, b 
  FROM links
  JOIN t_i ON (a = i_id OR b = i_id)
  WHERE id = x
UNION
SELECT a, b 
  FROM links
  JOIN t_o ON (a = o_id OR b = o_id)
  WHERE id = x
```

But for good index usage I suggest splitting it once more. It is even longer query but can be really fast even on bigger data with indexes on `t_i(id,i_id)`, `t_o(id,o_id)` `links(a)` and `links(b)`

```
SELECT a, b 
  FROM links
  JOIN t_i ON (a = i_id)
  WHERE id = x
UNION
SELECT a, b 
  FROM links
  JOIN t_i ON (b = i_id)
  WHERE id = x
UNION
SELECT a, b 
  FROM links
  JOIN t_o ON (a = o_id)
  WHERE id = x
UNION
SELECT a, b 
  FROM links
  JOIN t_o ON (b = o_id)
  WHERE id = x
```

Answer (score 1):

Other alternative's are:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.a, l.b 
FROM links l
LEFT JOIN t_i
    ON t_i.i_id IN (l.a, l.b)
LEFT JOIN t_o
    ON t_o.o_id IN (l.a, l.b)
WHERE COALESCE(t_i.i_id, t_o.o_id) IS NOT NULL;


SELECT l.a, l.b 
FROM links l
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM t_i 
    WHERE t_i.i_id IN (l.a, l.b)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 
    FROM t_o 
    WHERE t_o.o_id IN (l.a, l.b)
);


SELECT l.a, l.b 
FROM links l
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM t_i 
    WHERE t_i.i_id IN (l.a, l.b)
) OR EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM t_o 
    WHERE t_o.o_id IN (l.a, l.b)
);
```